# No me funcionan determinadas funciones en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, diccionarios, python-2.x

Estoy aprendiendo `Python` y he estado intentando hacer el siguiente ejercicio.

Escribir un programa que permita gestionar la base de datos de clientes de una empresa.
Los clientes se guardarán en un diccionario en el que la clave de cada cliente será su NIF y el valor será otro diccionario con los datos del cliente (Nombre, dirección, teléfono, correo, preferente), donde preferente tendrá el valor `True` si se trata de un cliente preferente.

El programa debe preguntar al usuario por una opción del siguiente menú:

```
(1) Añadir cliente
(2) Eliminar cliente
(3) Mostrar cliente
(4) Listar todos los clientes
(5) Listar clientes preferentes
(6) Terminar
```

En función de la opción elegida el programa tendrá que hacer lo siguiente:

1. Preguntar los datos del cliente, crear un diccionario con los datos y añadirlo a la base de datos.
2. Preguntar por el NIF del cliente y eliminar sus datos de la base de datos.
3. Preguntar por el NIF del cliente y mostrar sus datos.
4. Mostrar lista de todos los clientes de la base datos con su NIF y nombre.
5. Mostrar la lista de clientes preferentes de la base de datos con su NIF y nombre.
6. Terminar el programa.

Para hacer mi código más legible y por lo tanto mas limpio, he decidido que cada acción que realice el programa corresponda con una función y luego llamar a éstas cuando sea necesario.

### Y quedó tal que así;

```
clientes = dict()

def joinClientes(diccionario):
    c1 = str(input('Introduzca el nif con el siguiente formato (########-letra):'))
    nombre = str(input('Introduzca un nombre:'))
    direccion = str(input('Introduzca una dirección;'))
    telefono = int(input('Introduzca un teléfono:'))
    correo = input('Introduzca un correo')
    preferente = False
    p = str(input('Indique si es un cliente preferente(si/no)'));  p = p.lower()
    if p == 'SI':
        preferente = True
    v1 = dict(nombre = nombre,direccion=direccion,telefono=telefono,correo=correo,preferente=preferente,)
    diccionario[c1]=v1

def eliminarCliente(diccionario):
    x = int(input('Introduzca el nif del cliente a eliminar'))
    diccionario.pop(x,0)

def mostrarCliente(diccionario):
    x = int(input('Indique el nif del cliente que desea mostrar:'))
    if x not in diccionario:
        print('¡El nif del cliente no existe!')
    else:
        print(diccionario[x])

def mostrarPreferentes(diccionario):
    for x in diccionario:
        if diccionario[x]['preferente'] == True:
            print(x,diccionario[x]['nombre'])
#Ejecución del programa.

while True:
    print('1-Añadir cliente| 2- Eliminar cliente | 3-mostrar cliente | 4-listar todos los clientes | 5 listar clientes preferentes | 6 Terminar')
    option = int(input('Indique con números la operación que desea realizar:'))

    if option == 1:
        joinClientes(clientes)
    elif option == 2:
        eliminarCliente(clientes)#no funciona
    elif option == 3:
        mostrarCliente(clientes)
    elif option == 4:
        for x in clientes:
            print(x,clientes[x]['nombre'])
    elif option == 5:
        mostrarPreferentes(clientes)
    elif option == 6:
        print('fin programa')
        break
```

---

La función joinClientes() actúa sobre la variable(diccionario) añadiendo un nuevo cliente.
Pero las funciones mostrarCliente() | eliminarCliente() | mostrarPreferentes(). No optengo de ellas ningún comportamiento al llamarlas, salvo que haya pre-cargado los datos en la variable antes de entrar en el bloque while True:

Este comportamiento me tiene confundido ya que si funciona la función joinClientes() el resto de funciones deberían modificar o actuar sobre la variable(diccionario) perfectamente.
Si alguien pudiese ayudarme lo agradecería muchísimo.

Saludos.

Comment: `joinclientes` debe devolver el diccionario.  Sino pierdes lo que hayas modificado.  Este es un caso en el que seria mejor que usaras clases.  De esta forma puedes tener el diccionario como atributo, acceder a el como self.diccionario y asi tus functiones (metodos) no tienen que devolver nada. Echale un vistazo a un tutorial de clases e implementa tu codigo como una clase

Comment: Hola frustrateddeveloper, no, no es necesaro devolver nada, el problema es que en las funciones que presentan problemas, pides el **nif** con **x = int( input( 'Introduzca el nif del cliente a eliminar' ))**, cuando deberías usar **x = str( input( 'Introduzca el nif del cliente a eliminar' ))**, ya que el mismo está formado por letras y números. Corregido eso, tu código funciona como se espera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me siento en la necesidad de escribir esta respuesta porque, en este momento<sup>1</sup>, la [respuesta aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/593679/21) afirma:

> Las functiones(sic) que modifican diccionario deben devolverlo.

Y eso no es cierto, así que iniciaré aclarando ese punto:

## Las rutinas que modifican diccionarios lo pueden hacer directamente sobre la referencia que reciben como argumento

No tienen por qué retornar el diccionario mismo.
Podemos verlo con un ejemplo sencillo, mira esta rutina simple (similar a la que tienes en tu proyecto):

```
def agregar(diccionario):
    llave = input("llave: ")
    nombre = input("nombre: ")
    apellido = input("apellido: ")
    persona = {"nombre": nombre, "apellido": apellido}
    diccionario[llave] = persona


personas = {}
while True:
    agregar(personas)
    print(personas)
    if input("¿Quiere continuar? S/N: ").upper() != "S":
        break
```

Si observas detenidamente la rutina, no devuelve *nada* al final, y sin embargo, en cada iteración, irá imprimiendo el diccionario con los datos que le has agregado:

Puedes comprobar rápidamente que tu rutina para agregar clientes SI funciona sobre el diccionario que pasas como parámetro siguiendo la misma técnica para ver los cambios:

```
if option == 1:
    joinClientes(clientes)
    print(clientes)
```

## Por qué "no funcionan" tus rutinas entonces

Entonces, la pregunta del millón es, ¿por qué no funcionan tus rutinas?. Bueno, en buena medida ya lo habías descubierto y [publicado en tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/593687/21):

- Las rutinas `eliminarCliente` y `mostrarCliente` piden al usuario un (NIF) cliente, lo convierten a entero, y con ese valor realizan las operaciones sobre el diccionario, pero la rutina que agrega los clientes deja la llave como una cadena. Esto es algo que hay que resolver. O bien la rutina `joinCliente` deja esa llave como entero, o bien las otras rutinas usan una llave de tipo cadena.

  Si el NIF *debe* llevar un guión y una letra, como dice el *prompt* al pedirlo, entonces la única opción disponible es usar siempre *strings*.

Hay otros problemas en tu código, los vamos a resolver uno a uno y verás como todo mejora, a la vez que el código se simplifica.

1. [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) ya devuelve strings, no hace falta *convertir* a string lo que nos devuelve.

   ```
    nombre = str(input('Introduzca un nombre:'))
   ```

   Produce exactamente el mismo resultado que:

   ```
    nombre = input('Introduzca un nombre:')
   ```

   Por tanto, se puede eliminar casi todas las conversiones de la rutina `joinClientes()`.
2. La rutina `mostrarPreferentes` falla, porque busca clientes con la llave `'preferente'` en `True` y no encuentra ninguno. Esto es porque hay un *bug* en la rutina `joinClientes` y TODOS los clientes agregados quedan con este valor en `False`.

   Veamos tu código:

   ```
    p = str(input('Indique si es un cliente preferente(si/no)'));  p = p.lower()
    if p == 'SI':
        preferente = True
   ```

   En la primera línea hay dos sentencias. Al final verás que se encuentra `p = p.lower()`.

   Comenzaré diciendo que, esto está bien para el interprete de python. Este aceptaría todo un programa en una sola línea, o muy pocas. Pero para un humano es usualmente mejor tener una sentencia por línea:

   ```
    p = str(input('Indique si es un cliente preferente(si/no)'))
    p = p.lower()
    if p == 'SI':
        preferente = True
   ```

   Por otro lado, si realmente te quieres ahorrar esa línea, se pudo haber llamado al método `lower()` directamente sobre el resultado del input:

   ```
    p = input('Indique si es un cliente preferente(si/no)').lower()
    if p == 'SI':
        preferente = True
   ```

   Ahora, la comparación `p == "SI"` siempre va a devolver falso, simplemente porque en el paso anterior conviertes la cadena a minúsculas, con el método `lower()`. Puedes resolverlo convirtiendo a mayúsculas, o comparando con la cadena `"si"`.

   Simplificando aún más el código, no hace falta inicializar la variable ni el `if`, ya que una expresión de comparación devuelve un valor booleano que puede directamente asignarse a una variable.

   Es decir, no hace falta 4 líneas para esto:

   ```
    p = input('Indique si es un cliente preferente(si/no)').lower
    preferente = p == "si"
   ```

   Producirá el resultado deseado. Sé que esto quizás parezca sorprendente al inicio, y es una de las cosas que hay que *aprender* para salir de la *infancia booleana*. Me repito: Una operación de comparación produce un resultado booleano que se puede asignar a una variable.
3. Cuándo haces un `if` sobre una variable booleana, generalmente no hace falta compararla con valores como `True` o `False`, pues la variable ya tiene esos valores, que es lo que el `if` necesita. Es decir:

   ```
    if diccionario[x]['preferente'] == True:
   ```

   Es exactamente equivalente a simplemente:

   ```
    if diccionario[x]['preferente']:
   ```

   Y en mi opinión, es mucho más legible.  Si tuvieras que listar todos los clientes que no son preferentes, en lugar de esto:

   ```
    if diccionario[x]['preferente'] == False:
   ```

   Haz esto, que no solo es más legible, sino más elegante:

   ```
    if not diccionario[x]['preferente']:
   ```
4. Algo menores, pero siempre importantes es estandarizar la manera de pedir los datos. Algunos *prompts* terminan con `:`, otro con `;` y algunos sin nada. Tampoco dejan un espacio entre el *prompt* y el ingreso de datos del usuario. Eso brinda una experiencia confusa. Es mejor mantener un estándar y ser consistente.
5. Validaciones. Tu rutina para eliminar no valida si el cliente existe o no. Para el usuario sería deseable saber si ha cometido un error al introducir el NIF del cliente.

Con estas mejoras, tu programa original funcionará correctamente.

---

<sup>1</sup> Recuerda que puedes cambiar de respuesta aceptada y, por el bien de los futuros visitantes de este hilo durante la investigación de algún problema, lo hagas. En StackOverflow es muy importante que las respuestas sean de buena calidad y eso se refleja en los votos que reciben, pero también en qué respuesta es aceptada por el AP. Hacerlo correctamente es una responsabilidad que cada miembro de la comunidad lleva.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus correcciones es motivador para un principiante auto-didacta como yo y siendo mi primera vez en stackOverflow.

las sentencias :
x = input('texto').upper() o . lower()  
no sabía que eso era posible, me ayudará en mis próximos ejercicios y en mi aprendizaje sin duda.

Comment: En cuanto a la sentencia que me has corregido
if diccionario[x][preferente]== True:

lo había visto en los bucles while True:  por ejemplo(while variable:) sabía que una variable se podía utilizar como referencia booleana pero no hasta ese nivel. Te doy tu respuesta como aceptada, es mas completa y rigurosa.

Answer (score 2):

Si os fijáis en la función "joinClientes()", mirando el cuerpo de la función.
la variable interna con la que se "fabrica" o se "crea" la clave del diccionario, es en realidad un `str()`;

```
c1 = str(input('Introduzca el nif con el siguiente formato (########-letra):'))
```

Y si miráis en las funciones que dije que no se comportaban como yo esperaba, la variable que utilizo para rastrear la clave del diccionario es un INT.

pongo un ejemplo con la función `eliminarCliente()`:
fijaros en la variable x

```
x = int(input('Introduzca el nif del cliente a eliminar'))
```

Si lo dejas así;

```
x = input('Introduzca el nif del cliente a eliminar)
```

Entonces si funciona, porque le estas diciendo que busque una clave INTEGER a un diccionario que tiene claves STRING.